# Problem with Notation in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, notation

I am confused with the exclamation mark used in Steve Awodey's book *Category Theory.*  The following diagram is from page $98$:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>\boxed{\,!\;}\ \color{red}{???}>> 1 \\
@VVV @VV{\top}V \\
A @>>{\chi_{U}}> 2.
\end{CD}
$$

The book says that

> Therefore, we can rephrase the correspondence between subsets $U \subset A$ and their characteristic function $\chi_U:A \to 2$ in terms of pullbacks: (the picture above)

The thing I am not understanding is because that he used the notion of $!$ in the book first time (or maybe I did not read carefully enough). I do not know what he meant by exclamation?

Comment: It's just an arrow that's named $!$. In particular, it is the unique arrow into $1$ given by its universal property. (Often $!$ will be subscripted to be clearer, e.g. $!_U$, but the subscript is often omitted.)

Comment: $1$ is a terminal object in the category of sets. By $!$ (or $!_U$) he means the unique map from the object $U$ to the terminal object.

Comment: @DerekElkins that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of having an answer to this question (with a tip o' the hat to both Derek Elkins and Lord Shark the Unknown for their comments):

In the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{!}>> 1 \\
@VVV @VV{\top}V \\
A @>>{\chi_{U}}> 2,
\end{CD}
$$
the top arrows is labeled "$!$", which (naïvely) indicates that the arrow is simply named "$!$".  That being said, the name is not without motivation:  exclamation points are often used in mathematics to denote uniqueness.  For example, you might often see the notation "$\exists !x$", which is read "there exists a unique $x$".

In the context of category theory, 1 is a terminal object in the category of sets.  That is, if $U$ is any set, then there exists a unique morphism from $U$ to 1.  In notation, we might write
$$U \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathsf{Set})
\implies \exists ! f:U\to 1. $$
As the morphism $f$ is unique, we may as well label it "$!$" (or, if there is a risk of ambiguity, "$!_U$").